Add items to an PowerShell array, and process the array in batches
I have an array with strings:
$Names = @("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","Name8","Name9","Name10")

I want to do the following:
I want to have a Skip variable, where I will cut my array in chunks, and want to print my names with 5 seconds in between.
I have tried it by doing the following:
$BatchSkip = 5 


for($i = 0; $i -lt $names.Count; $i += $BatchSkip){
    $tempArray = $names |Select-Object -First $BatchSkip
    foreach ($name in $tempArray)
    {
        write-host $name 
    } Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

But this keeps printing the same names. What factor is missing in my code to implement that it 'loops' over my array?

If I correctly understood what you are trying to achieve, then this should work:
$Names = @("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","Name8","Name9","Name10")

$BatchSkip = 5

for($i = 0; $i -lt $names.Count; $i += $BatchSkip){
    $tempArray = $names[$i..($i+$BatchSkip-1)]
    foreach ($name in $tempArray)
    {
        write-host $name 
    } Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

Your tempArray did not contain the correct values of names, since there was no dependence on the loop variable i.

UPDATE: added (commented)alternative to piping to Select-Object
You never increase the value of -Skip in the loop. Thus it always returns the same values.
Also: you need to use -Index, not -Skip.
With -Skip the cmdlet only... well, SKIPS the first N items. But if you have 3000 items and you -Skip 5, then it will still process the other 2995.
With -Index otherwise you can tell Select-Object the exact range of values you want
Have some dirty code
$Names = 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8', 'Name9', 'Name10'
$BatchSkip = 5 

for ($Index = 0; $Index -lt $Names.Count; $Index += $BatchSkip) { 
            
    $Names | Select-Object -Index ($Index..($Index + $BatchSkip - 1)) | Write-Host

    # If you do not need further operations, it's possible to directly call the
    # item range you need like this:   
    # $Names[$Index..($Index + $BatchSkip - 1)] | Write-Host
            
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

}


One option to process in batches is to use the modulus operator:
$names = @("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","Name8","Name9","Name10")
$batchSkip = 5
$i = 1

foreach($name in $names) {
    $name
    
    if($i++ % $batchSkip -eq 0) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
}

The foreach loops around printing each name until $i is exactly divisible by $batchSkip.  That is, the remainder of the division is 0.  It then waits 5 seconds before carrying on until we've processed each item in the array.
